# CakePHP override plugin method

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.4

I'm using the CakeDC Tags plugin in my CakePHP project. I am using the [TagCloudHelper](https://github.com/CakeDC/tags/blob/master/View/Helper/TagCloudHelper.php) to output a list of links but this helper isn't formatting the links the way I would like. Specifically the method `_tagUrl($tag, $options)` is generating links with named parameters instead of using the query string.

Instead of

```
$options['url'][$options['named']] = $tag[$options['tagModel']]['keyname'];
```

I get the desired behavior with the following change

```
$options['url']['?'][$options['named']] = $tag[$options['tagModel']]['keyname'];
```

what is the best practice way of overriding this method? Do I make another class that extends TagCloudHelper? How then would I tell CakePHP to use my class instead of the plugin's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to override the helper with my own

```
// app/View/Helper/MyTagCloudHelper.php
App::uses('TagCloudHelper', 'Tags.View/Helper');

class MyTagCloudHelper extends TagCloudHelper {
    protected function _tagUrl($tag, $options) {
        $options['url']['?'][$options['named']] = $tag[$options['tagModel']]['keyname'];
        return $options['url'];
    }
}
```

Then in the controller

```
public $helpers = array('TagCloud' => array('className'=>'MyTagCloud'));
```

the className option let's you alias the name of the helper